# Perl IPC, child to send interrupt to parent

Tags: perl, ipc, inter-process-communicat

I am new to IPC, can anyone give me a simple IPC example with Perl where child can send a signal to its parent and parent could catch and react.
I tried many things, but it reacts only when I press control-C, but not every 5 seconds as I intended it to do...

Note: it works on Linux, but not on Windows.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $parent_pid = $$;
my $pid = fork();
if($pid == 0) {
   while (1) {
       print "In Child...\n";
       sleep 5;
       print "Sending INT to my parent...\n";
       kill 'INT', $parent_pid;
   }
}
else {
   sub catch_zap {
      my $signame = shift;
      print "Somebody sent me a SIG $signame!";
   }
   while(1){
      sleep 1;
      print "inside parent\n";
      eval {
         $SIG{INT} = \&catch_zap;
      };
   }
}
```

Comment: Your example seems to work for me. Perhaps the `Somebody sent (...)` message isn't shown in your case due to output buffering? Try adding a `\n` to that print statement.

Comment: I added `\n`, but its printing `Somebody sent me a SIG INT!` only when I hit control-c, not every 5 seconds.

Comment: Aah, it works good on Linux (perl version 5.14), but not on windows, I use perl 5.18 on windows

Comment: Not every aspect of Perl works on Windows (as well as it does on UNIX or at all sometimes) and it might also depend on the distribution of Perl on Windows (e.g. "DWIM Perl", "Strawberry Perl", "ActiveState Perl") you are using too.  Specifically I believe form(), Signals and Pipes which are modeled on how UNIX does stuff are emulated in Perl on Windows.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165867/perl-win32-signal-handling-between-perl-processes

Answer (score 0):

[Windows doesn't do signals](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=736477). You probably want to use [sockets](https://gist.github.com/gordolio/9371193) instead.

Comment: don't see how forks is relevant here; care to expand on that?